Copyright of infographs and where to deposit them?
Recently, a company designed infographs for some of our articles.
Infographs could be described as pictured one-page summaries of a research article. The head of the department paid for that service and then distributed the individual .pdf files to the respective investigators to promote our research.
Now there is a debate on copyright and where to upload these infographs to ensure proper citation is guaranteed. These infographs build on existing research, so they add nothing new. They just (graphically) summarize existing papers. Ideally, we would like to retain copyright but get a DOI. Is this possible / advisable or is it considered "redundant information"?
I found a comparable discussion on posters, however, I prefer something else than ResearchGate:
Where to upload conference posters and how to share them?
Any ideas? Thank you very much!

What does the contract with the company say about copyright? Start there. Either they own it, or your university owns it.

@ Jon Custer. I own the copyright. I am looking for an opportunity to retain it, despite uploading it online and without risking a "redundant publication" (e.g. a split in citations between the paper and the infographics).

Well, you retain copyright even if you upload it. And you can include the paper citation in the figure. caption (or add it to the infographic before uploading).
